# Azure CLI command to deploy the Azure logic app local ARM template

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template, azure-cli

I have downloaded the logic app template from one resource group , I have modified the template and that modified template I want to deploy it into the another resource group which I already created resource group along with storage account as well.

Can you please help me out with the Azure CLI command to deploy the local Arm template (Logic app).

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for `az group deployment create`, example:

```
az group deployment create -g MyResourceGroup --template-file azuredeploy.json \
                            --parameters @params.json --parameters https://mysite/params.json --parameters MyValue=This MyArray=@array.json
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/group/deployment?view=azure-cli-latest